# z3py: How to set Tactic configuration options whose names contain "."?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

The correct way of configuring tactics in z3.py is using "With".
E.g.

```
t = With(Tactic('simplify'), som=True)
```

However, some option names contain a "." in it, such as "arith.solver" in tactic "qflia". If we code in the same way

```
t = With(Tactic('qflia'), arith.solver=1)
```

The system gives an error "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression". I guess this is against the syntax rule for keyword in python.

How should I configure the options whose names contain "."? Or I am referring to a wrong list of tactics configuration options? The one I was using is output by command "(help-tactic)" on z3 not z3.py.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is instead of using "With", we should use "set_param" or "set_option". E.g.
`set_param('smt.phase_selection',5)`